# How to implement BeginScope of ILogger

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, logging, .net-8.0

How to implement BeginScope of ILogger

so i can extract the value i send to BeginScope inside Log function

```
   public sealed class MyLogger : ILogger
    {
        public IDisposable? BeginScope<TState>(TState state) where TState : notnull
        {
            // what to do here
        }
        public void Log<TState>(LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception? exception, Func<TState, Exception?, string> formatter)
        {
            // so i can get the value of the string App1 here
        }
    }
```

using (logger.BeginScope("app1"))

logger.LogInformation("Hello");

Comment: why are you implementing your own logger?

Comment: i want to write to files in qa and to db in prod in my own way

Comment: I would use the existing logging providers for that or use serilog

Comment: i dont see any reason to use unnecessary library and waste time config it if i can do it very simple by myself

Comment: Implementing a logger your self is no trivial task

Comment: Also the .net ones are open source so you can see how to implement one

Comment: can i use the built in BeginScope somehow in my custom logger?

Answer (score 0):

Just reference source code of `Logger`

```
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        IDisposable? ILogger.BeginScope<TState>(TState state)
        {
            return _logger.BeginScope(state);
        }

        void ILogger.Log<TState>(LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception? exception, Func<TState, Exception?, string> formatter)
        {
            _logger.Log(logLevel, eventId, state, exception, formatter);
        }
```